# asp.net ajax popupcontrol items show briefly on page

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a usercontrol on my page. The user control contains an ajax updatepanel  with a listbox in it. There is also a PopupControlExtender that is tied to that panel so when the user clicks on something the popup shows. That is all working fine except when my page initially loads I briefly see all the listbox items and then they go away.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:
style="display:none" on the updatepanel